# Java Finding Elements in Array

Tags: java

I have five arrays where I store incoming int numbers like:

```
int array1 = {1,6,..}
int array2 = {2,7,..}
.
.
int array5 = {5,10,..}
```

Now, what I have to do, search for next numbers in another arrays.

Like,

```
for(i = 0, i < array1.size ; i++){

int element = array1[0] ;

//here array2, array3, ..., array5 can have different size
search for array2 to find element+1
search for array3 to find element+2
.
.
search for array5 to find element+5
}
```

What I am doing right now is:

```
Run for loop for 0 to array2 size, to find element+1 (so for others)
```

However, it is quite slow. Can anybody give me some idea, how to make it faster (I can change array to any-other data-structure also).

Sorry, I make two mistakes while asking, what I should mention:

```
1) Arrays are sorted (incremental elements always).
2) Array elements are very few (2-3) so Binary Search will be expensive.
3) I have to perform the search for thousand times means when channel input pause, I have to perform search, then again channel start and I have to perform search ... so on.
```

Comment: Do your numbers always increment by a fixed amount (5 in the given example)?

Comment: Use `for (int i=0, ...)` in your for loops, otherwise be aware your `i` variable can be changed somewhere else in your method.

Comment: @Ozzy, no I do that. My codes o/P is correct. No issue with that. I want faster one.

Comment: You could try putting the values of array2, array3, etc into `HashSet<Integer>`, and then simply call `set2.contains(element);`

Comment: @GregCase, that is now I am thinking. Cool way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the arrays are sorted, use binary search to find the element instead of looping thru it for every single element.

Comment: your answer is correct. But, I forgot to mention something. I modified my question.

Comment: If the array size is always very small, then the linear search you're already doing is the best way to do it.